# Multiple downloads in angular - rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working with Angular and I have a problem downloading files. The first time I launch the event it downloads only one document. But without refreshing the page I download the same document again or another document, it is downloaded several times. I am using redux, This is how I'm implementing it.

```
   private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject<void>();

    transformDashboardToManual(){
    const validateObject: ManualLoadBlob = {
      Id: 0,
      CreatedUser: ' ',
      CreatedDate: new Date(),
      UpdatedUser: ' ',
      UpdatedDate: new Date(),
      ContainerName: 'container',
      Path: this.dataDashboard.FilePath,
      Description: this.dataDashboard.FileName
    };
    if (this.dataDashboard.IdAirlane == null)
    validateObject.Path = this.dataDashboard.Path + '/' + this.dataDashboard.FileName;
    else
    validateObject.Path = this.dataDashboard.Path + '/' + this.dataDashboard.IdAirlane + '/' +       this.dataDashboard.FileName;
     this.sharedService.ExistBlob(validateObject);
   }

  downloadFile() {
    this.transformDashboardToManual();
    this.sharedService.existBlob()
    .pipe(
      startWith(null),
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((exist) => {
        if (exist != null) {d
          if (!exist) {
            this.swal.Warning('El blob no existe');
          } else {
            this.service.DownloadBlobFile(
              this.dataDashboard.Path,
              this.dataDashboard.IdAirlane,
              this.dataDashboard.FileName
            );
            this.service
              .getDownloadBlobFile()
              .pipe(
                startWith(null),
                filter((url) => url && url != null),
                takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
            )
            .subscribe((url) => {
            if (url) {
              const link = document.createElement('a');
              link.download = 'descarga';
              link.href = url;
              link.target = '_blank';
              document.body.appendChild(link);
              link.click();
              document.body.removeChild(link);
            }
          });
        }        
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

The validations and execution of the API are correct, the problem is that when I try to download another file or the same one, what happens before is that it is downloaded multiple times. I still can't understand why this is.

I have tried to call in the function the method that sends the information to the api and inside the ngOnInit I put the service that has the observable and there I put the takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe). I also tried to put it in the same function but it still doesn't take it into account. I'm running out of ideas. Can you help me a little or give me some light?